# Errors when compiling Raylib game to WebAssembly

Tags: c++, emscripten, raylib

I've been trying to compile a game written in Raylib and C++ to WebAssembly with this command:
`emcc main.cpp -o quickdodge.html -s USE_GLFW=3 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s ASYNCIFY=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s ASSERTIONS=2 -Ic:/raylib/raylib/src --preload-file 8bitloop.wav`

However, when I attempt to run it, I get the following errors:

```
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: IsKeyDown
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: IsKeyDown
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: IsKeyDown
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: IsKeyDown
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: SetRandomSeed
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: GetRandomValue
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: GetRandomValue
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: InitWindow
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: InitAudioDevice
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: SetTargetFPS
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: LoadMusicStream
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: PlayMusicStream
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: WindowShouldClose
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: BeginDrawing
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: UpdateMusicStream
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: ClearBackground
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: MeasureText
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: MeasureText
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: MeasureText
wasm-ld: error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o: undefined symbol: MeasureText
wasm-ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)
emcc: error: 'C:/emsdk/upstream/bin\wasm-ld.exe -o quickdodge.wasm C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_re7kgthv\main_0.o -LC:\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\lib\wasm32-emscripten -lGL-webgl2-full_es3 -lal -lhtml5 -lstubs-debug -lnoexit -lc-debug -ldlmalloc-debug -lcompiler_rt -lc++-noexcept -lc++abi-debug-noexcept -lsockets -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx_iluw25libemscripten_js_symbols.so --export-if-defined=main --export-if-defined=__start_em_asm --export-if-defined=__stop_em_asm --export-if-defined=__start_em_lib_deps --export-if-defined=__stop_em_lib_deps --export-if-defined=__start_em_js --export-if-defined=__stop_em_js --export-if-defined=__main_argc_argv --export-if-defined=fflush --export=emscripten_stack_get_end --export=emscripten_stack_get_free --export=emscripten_stack_get_base --export=emscripten_stack_get_current --export=emscripten_stack_init --export=stackSave --export=stackRestore --export=stackAlloc --export=__errno_location --export=__get_temp_ret --export=__set_temp_ret --export=__wasm_call_ctors --export=malloc --export=free --export-table -z stack-size=65536 --initial-memory=16777216 --max-memory=2147483648 --no-entry --stack-first --table-base=1' failed (returned 1)
```

How can I successfully compile my game to WebAssembly?

I've ensured all necessary packages are installed and I know I linked to my raylib folder correctly. I was expecting it to output an .html, .js, .wasm and .data file like it's supposed to.

Comment: I would expect to see some raylib libraries mentioned in the compiler's command line like this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76541517/i32-load-error-while-trying-to-run-compiled-to-webassembly-c-raylib-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76541517/i32-load-error-while-trying-to-run-compiled-to-webassembly-c-raylib-game)